# Why isn't JMockit's @Injectable applied to all relevant fields?

Tags: unit-testing, jmockit

In the JUnit test with JMockit I use the `@Injectable` annotation to initialize the fields which are in production code initialized via Spring DI.

I use the implementation of a type in several classes. 
Why isn't `C` as an implementation of `IC` injected in the mock of the type `A`, like it is injected in the types `B` and `D` in the below mentioned test method?

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class A {
    @Autowired IC c;
    public IC getC() { return c; }

    // do something using C in the method body
    public void doSomething() {}
}

@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class B {
    @Autowired IC c;
    public IC getC() { return c; }

    // do something using C in the method body
    public void doSomething() {}
}

public interface IC { void doSomething(); }

@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class C implements IC {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {}
}

@Service
public class D {
    @Autowired IC c;
    @Autowired B b;
    @Autowired A a;

    public IC getC() { return c; }
    public B getB() { return b; }
    public A getA() { return a; }
}

public class TestClass {
    @Tested(fullyInitialized = true) D d;
    @Injectable IC c;
    @Tested @Injectable A a;
    @Tested @Injectable B b;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // expectations are recorded here
        assertNotNull(d.getC());
        assertNotNull(d.getB().getC());
        // Null reference 
        assertNotNull(d.getA().getC());
    }
}
```

**Edit:** 
`@Tested` and the use cases of `C` have been added to the code example. The annotation has been used to inject `C` into `A` and `B` to finally use it in some of their methods.

**Edit 2:**
Is it allowed to use `@Tested` this way for more than one field in a test class to extend the unit which is tested?

Comment: I don't get any null reference in this test. `D` gets instantiated with all three fields `a`, `b`, and `c` set from the corresponding `@Injectable` fields in the test class. Note that using `fullyInitialized = true` has no effect in this case, since all fields in the `@Tested` class have matching `@Injectable`s.

Comment: @Rogério: Thanks for the feedback. You're right. However I have added the missing parts of the code to give you a complete picture of the test case so that you can check why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been fixed in jmockit 1.25. Make sure you use the latest version.